# django payment gateway

Tags: django, payment, gateways

I require a simplest payment gateway in which user comes in click on buy button enters his card details and whatever the process includes to generate a reciept i want in a very simple manner.i have searched alot but i am not able to understand i am trying to understand paypal..
please suggest me a simplest payment gateway in django.I am developing a project and i am stuck very badly in it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

simplest? If you require custom amounts - paypal it is. Read this: http://uswaretech.com/blog/2008/11/using-paypal-with-django/ or https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal

If you require even simpler way and you don't care about strict payments amounts and still want easy donations, use flattr, then all you will need to do is to add facebook/digg-like button. More: https://flattr.com